# url/slide parameters not appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-comments, lightgallery

I'm using lightGallery and facebook comment/like plugin.

Can't seem to figure out why there's not a linkback to the full url whenever someone uses fb-comments for tagging/linking.

For me: ***page#lg=16&slide=1*** becomes "***page?fb_action_ids=......&fb_action_types=og.comments***".

Gets the page but no slide/photo.

In the lightGallery comment box demo the parameters get appended: ***og.comments#lg=1&slide=0*** and therefore gets the desired slide/photo.

"So do the same thing..." - I thought I was... But is not working out the same.

When clicking the facebook like button the user shares the page/canonical link but not the full url with the gallery slide parameters. Same as above.

I'm sure this isn't a lightGallery issue but something dumb on my part.

If just someone could figure out how dumb I am.

Would really appreciate any advice :)

Comment: URL Fragments are ignored by Facebook, you would need to use GET parameters for unique URLs.

Comment: You might be right but it works in this demo: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/comment-box.html